# Maven & InventoryClickEvent.getClickedInventory();

Tags: maven, bukkit, cannot-find-symbol

Whilst coding a fun new trash can for a Minecraft server network that I develop for, I came across a pretty strange, and therefore infuriating, bug concerning Maven. I've been using it for a year or two now and have only gotten a single build error before, when I first started using it. Suddenly, this problem has shown itself.

The red arrows indicate the lines that are causing the build failure.

[image: Image 1]

This is a screenshot of the Maven logs that are causing the issue.

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, according to the [Bukkit API docs](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/) (note that [the official docs](http://jd.bukkit.org/) seem to be down, thus third party), the class `InventoryClickEvent` has no method `getClickedInventory()`.

This fact definitely explains [your compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean). The error comes from your Java compiler, Maven has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I'm on the Spigot API which is a spinoff of the Bukkit API that has been optimized. That's a pretty drastic method change, but I tried it and it magically works. I wonder why the .getClickedInventory() method is still even there. Thanks for your help, your answer has been marked as the solution.